# C# List getting same value

Tags: c#, list

oh pleasee someone explain to me why is this happening...

```
public List<EmployeeHeader> GetEmployees()
        {
            List<EmployeeHeader> eh = new List<EmployeeHeader>();
            string query = "SELECT " +
                           "     firstName, lastName " +
                           "FROM" +
                           "     tbEmployee ";

            DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = db.getBD(query);

            int CountRows = dt.Rows.Count;

            EmployeeHeader emp = new EmployeeHeader();

            for(int i = 0; i < CountRows; i++)
            {
                emp.firstName = dt.Rows[i]["firstName"].ToString();
                emp.lastName = dt.Rows[i]["lastName"].ToString();
                eh.Add(emp);
            }

            return eh;
```

this is the class:

```
public class EmployeeHeader
    {
        public string firstName { get; set;}
        public string lastName {get; set;}

    }
```

and the end result is...

```
<ArrayOfEmployeeHeader xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.istec.pt/">
<EmployeeHeader>
<firstName>Hugo</firstName>
<lastName>Almeida</lastName>
</EmployeeHeader>
<EmployeeHeader>
<firstName>Hugo</firstName>
<lastName>Almeida</lastName>
</EmployeeHeader>
<EmployeeHeader>
<firstName>Hugo</firstName>
<lastName>Almeida</lastName>
</EmployeeHeader>
<EmployeeHeader>
<firstName>Hugo</firstName>
<lastName>Almeida</lastName>
</EmployeeHeader>
<EmployeeHeader>
<firstName>Hugo</firstName>
<lastName>Almeida</lastName>
</EmployeeHeader>
</ArrayOfEmployeeHeader>
```

Always the same name!!! I have debuged, step by step,  the correct names are getting in to the list but in the end... I get the same names!!

Probably a silly mistake but could please someone point it for me please?

thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are setting properties of the same instance. Put the line below **inside** the loop:

```
EmployeeHeader emp = new EmployeeHeader();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        for(int i = 0; i < CountRows; i++)
        {
            EmployeeHeader emp = new EmployeeHeader();
            emp.firstName = dt.Rows[i]["firstName"].ToString();
            emp.lastName = dt.Rows[i]["lastName"].ToString();
            eh.Add(emp);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < CountRows; i++)
        {
            EmployeeHeader emp = new EmployeeHeader();
            emp.firstName = dt.Rows[i]["firstName"].ToString();
            emp.lastName = dt.Rows[i]["lastName"].ToString();
            eh.Add(emp);
        }
```